# cv2.imshow() is not working properly in PyCharm (MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Environment:

- interpreter: Python 3.9.0
- OS: macOS Big Sur

This simple code is running fine with no errors; however, no image is produced and nothing is displayed, and I'm forced to manually stop the code and interrupt it to exit, otherwise it just seems to run forever? This exact same code used to work fine on my windows laptop. Any clue? The code:

```
import cv2

CV_cat = cv2.imread('Cat.jpg')
cv2.imshow('displaymywindows', CV_cat)
cv2.waitKey(1500)
```

Comment: Did you try `cv2.waitKey(0)`?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately though, that didn't work either

Comment: For me, the value `1500` opened and closed immediately the image both on Pycharm (community 2020.2) and terminal. The value `0` worked fine on both. Did you try to run it from the Mac terminal?

Comment: @PauloMarques is it working for you on macOS Big Sur?

Comment: @SSB95, not tested on Big Sur. It is working on Catalina.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PauloMarques. I guess something went wrong with my installation of opencv with python but I can confirm now that it works on Big Sur as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ubuntu 18.04 and Anaconda environment I was getting the error with Pycharm as

> process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by
> signal 11 sigsegv)

Solved it by `pip install opencv-python-headless` in addition to `pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 4):

```
import cv2

CV_cat = cv2.imread('Cat.jpg')
cv2.imshow('displaymywindows', CV_cat)
cv2.waitKey(0)   #wait for a keyboard input
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

try this code

Comment: This is exactly what I get: https://ibb.co/F0LFCCx (I feel the screenshot might explain my case better)

Answer (score 3):

First, try whether you can create a window or not.

```py
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('displaymywindows', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

- From the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html):

  - > There is a special case where you can already create a window and load image to it later. In that case, you can specify whether window is resizable or not. It is done with the function cv2.namedWindow(). By default, the flag is cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE. But if you specify flag to be cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL, you can resize window. It will be helpful when image is too large in dimension and adding track bar to windows.

Then load read and load your image:

```py
CV_cat = cv2.imread('car.png')
cv2.imshow('displaymywindows', CV_cat)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`waitKey(0)` means wait till the user press a key.

Updated (error-handling is added)

---

```py
import cv2
import sys

try:
    cv2.namedWindow('displaymywindows', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    CV_cat = cv2.imread('car.png')
    cv2.imshow('displaymywindows', CV_cat)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print("Error: {}".format(e))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same thing happens. The python rocket pops up with nothing showing, and the code acts as if it was running forever (looping), and I'm forced to interrupt it

Comment: No, just running it directly from PyCharm script

Comment: Could you please run my Updated version of my code? Lets see if there is any error.

Comment: Thanks for the update! No error is produced, this is exactly what happens: https://ibb.co/HYd53Tn

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned it earlier (edited the post). It's 3.9

Comment: Yes i tested in my mac

Comment: Fixed it by using conda environment instead of pip, and using the following commands in conda: "pip install opencv-python", then "pip install opencv-python-headless"

Comment: This is very strange, pip environment should not have this kind of problems. Glad you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After updating Xcode everything worked for me.